# Restarting Hyper-V service without restarting VM's

Tags: hyper-v, windows-server-2016

I went to perform a regular task of checkign a setting on a VM, did a right click and the Hyper-V Manager hung, i have a popuo 'Microsoft Management Console' with the loading progress bar, but I cannot close it, nor close the Hyper-V Manager

I tried launching a new instance of Hyper-V Manager, which worked, but anything I do in it just hangs it again.

All VM's are working as normal.

I'd like to close the instance of MMC that is running from within Task Manager, but this is a production server and I really do not want to lose the VM's that are running if I do so, as all VM's are working perfectly despite this issue.

I'm unsure of what may happen in this scenario by force closing MMC from within Task Manager... Are the VM's likely to impacted if I do this?

Other than that, the only thing I can think of is to schedule planned maintenance and do it an an agreed time and risk having to lose the VM's or, at worst, reboot the host.

Just wondering if anyone had seen same behaviour and what the likely impact of force quitting  the 'Microsoft Management Console' from within Task Manager might do to the operation of the working VM's.

The host is Windows Server 2016.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can close the MMC from task manager and the VMs will keep running.

You can also restart the `Virtual Machine Management` service as well. I've had to do that once or twice when I've had an issue with the management console.

[image]

Comment: Hi Deaton, thank you. I actually just found this after improving my Google search skills :-/ https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/69e6dcbd-fbe3-43e0-a7b3-65111fbdf00a/will-the-running-vms-be-impacted-if-i-restart-the-quothyperv-virtual-machine-managementquot?forum=winserverhyperv Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome. :)